# Nginx reverse proxy return 502

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm very new to nginx and server game and i'm trying to setup a reverse proxy. Basically what i need is when i enter my server ip it should open a particular website (Ex: https://example.com).

So for example if i enter my ip (Ex: 45.10.127.942) it should open the website example.com , but the url should remain as http://45.10.127.942.

I tried to set my server configuration as follows but it returns a 502 error.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
    }
}
```

It returns a 502 error. Can you please explain what i need to do?

Comment: 502 http core returned when proxy destination service is down or unavailble.

Comment: make sure that your destination service is up and response to yout request with http.
maybe example.com is on https 
try it

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this in your configuration file:

```
server {
  root /var/www/html;
  
  server_name _;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Place the index.html file in `root` folder specified.
Then just restart the NGINX and it should work.

What is the problem with your configuration file is you should not `proxy_pass`.
If you want to open the other website, you should have DNS record pointing to that IP. What actually happens is the thing you are trying to do is known as `CLICKJACKING`. For more details, search CLICKJACKING on google and you will find a lot of references.